# use power series to evaluate an integral

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

This is the integral:

$$ 
a=\int_0^{\pi/2} \left(1 - 0.5(\sin x)^2\right)^{-1/2}\,\mathrm dx
$$

I tried using a binomial expansion multiple times and each time I get a sum which contains a trigonometric function raised to the power of $n$ or $2n$. I never get a power series which can be readily integrated. Here is one example:

$$
a=\sqrt{2}\int_0^{\pi/2} 1+ \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n\cdot1\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7\cdots(2n-1)}{n!\cdot2^n}(\cos x)^{2n}\,\mathrm dx
$$

What is the easiest way for me to solve the problem? I am near the end of calculus $2$.

Comment: In addition to Claude Leibovici's answer, the series expansion of the Complete Elliptic Integral of first kind is : 
$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-z\:\sin^2(x)}}=\text{EllipticK(z)}=\frac{\pi}{2}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left( \frac{\left(\frac12\right)_k}{k!}\right)^2 \left(z\right)^k$$
where $\left(\frac12\right)_k$ denotes the Pochhammer function : http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PochhammerSymbol.html

in case of $z=\frac12$ the result is :  a=EllipticK$(\frac12)=1.85407467730137$

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CompleteEllipticIntegraloftheFirstKind.html

Comment: @JJacquelin. This is fine but you start from the result of the integation which is not known at this poinr.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not know what you have been precisely asked but, if it is via a power series you need to expand the integrand in terms of $x$.

If this is the case, start with the usual
$$\sin(x)=x-\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^5}{120}-\frac{x^7}{5040}+\frac{x^9}{362880}+O\left(x^{11}\right)$$ Use the binomial expansion to square it
$$\sin^2(x)=x^2-\frac{x^4}{3}+\frac{2 x^6}{45}-\frac{x^8}{315}+\frac{2
   x^{10}}{14175}+O\left(x^{12}\right)$$
$$1-\frac 12\sin^2(x)=1-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{6}-\frac{x^6}{45}+\frac{x^8}{630}-\frac{x^{10}}{14175}+O\left(x^{12}\right)$$
$$\sqrt{1-\frac 12\sin^2(x)}=1-\frac{x^2}{4}+\frac{5 x^4}{96}+\frac{11 x^6}{5760}-\frac{11 x^8}{129024}-\frac{18121
   x^{10}}{116121600}+O\left(x^{12}\right)$$ Long division now
$$\frac 1 {\sqrt{1-\frac 12\sin^2(x)}}=1+\frac{x^2}{4}+\frac{x^4}{96}-\frac{71 x^6}{5760}-\frac{2591 x^8}{645120}-\frac{23759
   x^{10}}{116121600}+O\left(x^{12}\right)$$ and now, integrate termwise.

Using this truncated expansion and the given bounds, you should end with something like $1.84350$ while the exact value is $1.85407$

**Edit**

If you want to make the series expansion keeping the trigonometric function, considering the most general case (as @JJacquelin did), consider
$$\frac 1 {\sqrt{1-a\sin^2(x)}}=\frac 1 {\sqrt{1-t}}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \binom{-\frac{1}{2}}{n} t^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \binom{-\frac{1}{2}}{n}a^n sin^{2n}(x)$$ which makes
$$I=\int_0^{\frac \pi 2}\frac {dx} {\sqrt{1-a\sin^2(x)}}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \binom{-\frac{1}{2}}{n}a^n \int_0^{\frac \pi 2}sin^{2n}(x)\,dx$$ Any table of definite integrals will give
$$\int_0^{\frac \pi 2}sin^{2n}(x)\,dx=\frac{\sqrt{\pi }\, \Gamma \left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{2 \Gamma (n+1)}$$ So, as a result
$$I=\frac{\sqrt{\pi }} 2\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \binom{-\frac{1}{2}}{n} \frac{ \Gamma \left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{ \Gamma (n+1)}a^n$$  which is convergent if $a<1$ since
$$b_n=(-1)^n \binom{-\frac{1}{2}}{n} \frac{ \Gamma \left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{ \Gamma (n+1)}a^n\implies \frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}=\frac{a (2 n+1)^2}{4 (n+1)^2}=a-\frac{a}{n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$ For sure, as JJacquelin wrote
$I=K(a)$.

For $a=\frac 12$, the partial sums concerge quite fast
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
p & S_p \\
 0 & 1.57080 \\
 1 & 1.76715 \\
 2 & 1.82237 \\
 3 & 1.84154 \\
 4 & 1.84888 \\
 5 & 1.85186 \\
 6 & 1.85311 \\
 7 & 1.85364 \\
 8 & 1.85388 \\
 9 & 1.85399 \\
 10 & 1.85403 \\
 11 & 1.85406 \\
 12 & 1.85407
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Thank you very much. I plan to lookup how you managed to take a square root of a series there, as well as to figure out how one is supposed to derive the formula JJacquelin posted above. After that I should be able to provide the answer accurate to 0.0005, as the question asked me to do.